# Can anyone explain what is this error? Uncaught TypeError: cannot read property 'innerHTML' of null This is the line which is causing the issue:

Tags: javascript

Can anyone explain what is this error?

> Uncaught TypeError: cannot read property 'innerHTML' of null

This is the line which is causing the issue:

```
  if (productT[i].innerHTML==productName )
```

Can anyone explain what is this error?

Comment: What is unclear about an error message such as _“Cannot read property `innerHTML` of `null`”_? You can’t read properties of `null`, but that’s what happens at `productT[i].innerHTML` because `productT[i]` is `null`; it’s trying to get `innerHTML` off of `null` — not possible. If you don’t know why `productT[i]` is `null`, use the debugger or look at intermediate values: `console.log({ productT, i });`. In Firefox, you can click the “[\[Learn more\]](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Unexpected_type)” link next to the error message.

Comment: If you can show what `productT` "looks" like then we can help you. Is it an html element or multiple elements, or is it an array or object ?

Comment: Learn about [how to debug small programs](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs). Try using your browser’s [debug capabilities](//ali-dev.medium.com/how-to-easily-debug-in-javascript-5bac70f94f1a). See [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](/q/25385173/4642212). Use linters like [ESLint](//eslint.org/play) or [JSHint](//jshint.com) to find problems with your code immediately.

Answer (score 1):

the `productT[i]` is `null`, please check the values of `productT[i]` and avoid referencing their properties if they are `null`.

Comment: If `productT[i]` is null, what values do you expect the op to check?

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling you that at the line of

```
productT[i].innerHTML==productName
```

you tried to read the `innerHTML` property of `null`. Since you have read the `innerHTML` property of `productT[i]`, it follows that `productT[i]` is `null`. It is possible that it is validly `null`, in which case you will need to keep that into account by something like:

```
((!productT[i]) || productT[i].innerHTML)==productName
```

or, it's also possible that your i'th value should not be `null`, in which case the error is not the problem, only its symptom. You should think this through and answer the following question to yourself:

**Is it valid to have productT[i] being `null`?**

and then the answer to the problem will be simple.